# When insert data with insert select into with additional data show error Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

When insert data with insert select into with additional data show error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.

Here is my code

```sql
INSERT INTO [database].[dbo].[table1] (userid_fk,
                                       year,
                                       month,
                                       leaveCredit,
                                       leaveCreditReason,
                                       addedOn,
                                       addedBy)
VALUES ((SELECT userid
         FROM [database].[dbo].[table2]
         WHERE user_isactive = 1
           AND date_of_joining < DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))), YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1.5, 'monthly leave', GETDATE(), '1');
```

Comment: your select statement returns more than 1 record. Please check your select query for getting userid_fk.. re writing your select query for getting only 1 record or you can use top 1 for that. write logic based on your requirement.

Comment: The error is pretty clear here; Your subquery returned more than 1 value and that's not allowed in the context the subquery is it (a scalar value is expected). What about said error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` statement is not a good candidate to write within `values` clause.

First, its clear that the `select` query is returning more than 1 rows, make sure if you want to insert only one row, then use some filter conditions or `top` operator.

Also the insert statement itself contains 7 columns (`userid_fk,year,month,leaveCredit,leaveCreditReason,addedOn,addedBy`), while the select statement contains only 1 column (`userid` ).

The number of columns should be same in `insert` and `select`.

You can change the query to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [database].[dbo].[table1] (userid_fk,year,month,leaveCredit,leaveCreditReason,addedOn,addedBy)
SELECT userid_fk, year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1.5, 'monthly leave', getdate(), '1'
FROM [database].[dbo].[table2] 
WHERE user_isactive=1 
AND date_of_joining < DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
```